# Unable to write a csv file in S3 bucket from R

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to write a csv file to an Amazon S3 bucket using the following code

```
s3write_using(gene_read_counts, FUN = write.csv, object = "gene_read_counts_test.csv", bucket = "test-bioinformatics-dev-bkt/research/bioinformatics/colo_final/data/processed/colorectal", row.names=FALSE)
```

I am getting the following error

> File size is 71619789. Consider setting 'multipart = TRUE'.
>   Error in parse_aws_s3_response(r, Sig, verbose = verbose) : Forbidden (HTTP 403).

Answer (score 1):

While looking at the error there could be 2 aspects.

1. Seems the error suggesting using AWS-S3 multipart upload while uploading the big file. Multi part upload provides  faster, more flexible uploads into Amazon S3.  It could be achieved by

   - Split the Objects/file in small chunks.
   - Upload initialization using `CreateMultipartUpload`  of S3 API.
   - Upload part of objects using multipart upload. use `UploadPartCopy` operation of S3 API
   - Complete Multipart Upload. use `CompleteMultipartUpload` operation of S3 API.
   - Meanwhile must implement `AbortMultipartUpload` if any of the part uploaded failed. Using `AbortMultipartUpload`, the storage consumed by any previously uploaded parts will be freed.

   Please refer below AWS documentations. 
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CreateMultipartUpload.html
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_UploadPart.html
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CompleteMultipartUpload.html
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_AbortMultipartUpload.html
2. Forbidden (HTTP 403) error suggest that permission denied. In this case please check the IAM roles if the user has the permission to access the S3 objects.

Since you are using 'R' language for writing file in S3. I would recommend use `Put_Object` function  and set `multipart = TRUE` in the function to upload file partwise.

you can use below code

```
   put_object(filename, object, bucketname, multipart = TRUE, acl = c("private",
     "public-read", "public-read-write", "aws-exec-read", "authenticated-read",
     "bucket-owner-read", "bucket-owner-full-control"), headers = list(), ...)
```

when you say  `multipart = TRUE` in above function, it will create parts or chunks of the provided objects and upload it partwise in S3.

Comment: Thanks can you please help with an example.

Comment: @drpreeti3628, I have updated my answer to use of Put_object function for multipart upload

Comment: I tried the following code, but getting the below error- > x <- rawConnection(raw(0), "w")
> utils::write.csv(gene_read_counts, x)
> put_object(rawConnectionValue(x), file = gene_read_counts, object = "/data/processed/gene_read_counts_test2.csv", bucket = "kite-bioinformatics-dev-bkt", multipart = TRUE, acl = c("private", "public-read", "public-read-write", "aws-exec-read", "authenticated-read", "bucket-owner-read", "bucket-owner-full-control"), headers = c('x-amz-server-side-encryption' = 'AES256'))
Error: Argument object must be of type character or raw vector if serialize is FALSE